# Does Enterprise Account Renewal effect installed application?

Tags: ios

I need a solid answer for my case. My company has an Enterprise account and we have already used it to publish some apps to our clients through private store. The account has been renewed for another year.

Activation Date: February 2, 2023 Expiration Date: February 2, 2024

My question, is there any action that should be taken like uploading a new version of the app before this date or even after this date ?

Please note that the certification(used to signed the app) expires in next October 2023.

The case if very critical and we don't want the app to be stopped suddenly.

Comment: You should watch [this](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/304). You will need to distribute a new provisioning profile once per year and you must install a new version once every three years.  BTW you should not use an enterprise program to publish apps to your clients; This is a violation of the enterprise agreement.  The enterprise program should only be used to distribute apps to your own employees company owned devices.  You should look at custom distribution or unlisted distribution.

Comment: @Paulw11 I will check the video. For your second point it is not my decision to go to enterprise account and as I remember the company has been enforced by Apple to use this account type because the app is not for the public purpose.

Comment: Things have changed in recent years (although the use of the Enterprise program for non-employees has never been legitimate).  The same video also discusses custom apps (which is probably what you should use).  [Unlisted apps](https://developer.apple.com/support/unlisted-app-distribution/) are newer than that video.  The advantage of custom apps and unlisted apps are that they are Apple signed and therefore never expire.

Comment: I have watched the video but it didn't answer my question. I know that our current solution is not the proper one but I need a solution for this until we pick the right program.

Comment: Your current build will stop working when its embedded provisioning profile expires. This is after 1 year, or when the certificate that signed it expires, which is after 3 years. So if your current version was built less than a year ago you are *probably* all right for now, as long as the signing certificate doesn't expire.